# ListView WebPart

Tags: list, web-part, list-view, data-view-web-part

Is there any option to display sharepoint list which is in one domian on the sharepoint site which is on other domain? I'm not interested in solution which use iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a BDC model to support an External list from the respective domain's database.